# Attempting to convert a char array to a string and then comparing length

Tags: c#

My `char[]` both consist of exactly one element. My job is to compare the length of the element of the first array to the one of the second.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace FirstLecture
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] ints = {char.Parse(Console.ReadLine())};

            char[] ints2 = {char.Parse(Console.ReadLine())};

            string s1 = new string(ints);
            string s2 = new string(ints2);

            if (s1.Length > s2.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">");
            }
            else if (s1.Length < s2.Length)
            {   
                Console.WriteLine("<");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("=");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program in the console, I get `String must be exactly one character long`. I'm assuming there is some sort of a data type conversion error, cannot pin point it. Is this the case?

Comment: `char` type must be exactlly 1 simbol. char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) might return more then one (f.e., user enters `12`).

Answer (score 2):

`char.Parse` only parses one single character, not the entire string you read from `Console.ReadLine` (so if you just type 'A' in your console, it should work).

Instead, you could just assign the string to the character array:

```
char[] ints = Console.ReadLine().ToArray();
```

It seems useless though since you immediate after assigning the characters construct a string out of it again. Both input and resulting strings should be the same.

This should be okay:

```
string s1 = Console.ReadLine();
```